# XMLHttpRequest request is resultin in ReadyState 4 and status is 200

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a XMLHttpRequest Request to a content which is on local, runnin on local webserver from a HTML File and javascript residing locally.

it will hit the webserver request, and then even thou it sends the data back, in my javascript, at once I get readyState 4 and status as 0.

If i try putting the pages in the webserver foloder and access them as webpage slke http;//localhost/ filename then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is to do with the fact that HTTP status codes are returned by web servers and, since you're accessing the local file system, a status code can't be returned -- hence `Unknown (0)`.   Some links:

- [Using XMLHttpRequest / Example: Non-HTTP synchronous request - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#section_3)
- [XMLHttpRequest status = 0 and XMLHttpRequest statusText = unknown](http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/XMLHttpRequest.html)

---

Following your comments, it's a little clearer as to what is causing your problem.  XMLHttpRequests are restricted in each browser by the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  If you try to access a file on a different domain, port or protocol the request will return a status code of 0 and nothing for `responseText`.  The most suitable workaround for the time being is [JSON with Padding](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding).

Comment: I think I put the question in a wrong way.. Let me give more details:
i have test.html in my c:\ drive and I have a local webserver runnin in qt, and i have some plugin written to that webserver which will get the request and send some response text "hello".

in test.html i m making a xml xhr request which will make a GET request like http://localhost:8080/test which will return the text "hello" by that plugin.

Now if I directly open test.html from C:\ it doesnt work, i mean i get response 4 and status 0, and response text nothing.. but the request is passing through webserver and plugin.

Comment: Also to mention, if I put test.html in the webserver's folder, and make  arequest to that page like.. http://localhost:8080/test.html it works fine.

Comment: @deepak: I see what you mean now.  I've updated my answer to reflect the problem you're experiencing.